# What tense is "Having had..."?

Tags: tenses, future-perfect

This statement is from many 12-step recovery programs (primarily Alcoholics Anonymous):

"Step 12. *Having had* a spiritual awakening as the result of these steps, we tried to carry this message to alcoholics, and to practice these principles in all our affairs.”

I suspect it is future perfect; can anyone clarify this for me?

Comment: What is the reason for you suspecting it's future perfect? If you've done prior research, please give us as much information as you can. :)

Comment: It is certainly not the *future perfect* (which would be *I shall have had a...). Indeed it is not a verb, but an adjectival phrase qualifying the subject *we*.

Comment: "Having had" is the perfect tense. The auxiliary verb "having" is a present (perfect) participle combining with past participle "had" to locate the situation in past time. "Having had a spiritual awakening as the result of these steps", is a gerund-participial clause whose subject (from the matrix clause) is "we". Notice also that "had" has a direct object "a spiritual awakening as the result of these steps".

Comment: Thanks! I suspected it was future because I'm an idiot at this. Back to the books.

Comment: The place this appears in the AA book is *before* the reader has actually started the progression through the steps (or only partway through). I was looking at it, for no particular reason, as a promise of something yet to come for the reader (future) rather than a statement of the circumstances of those ('we') who were already at that point (present).

Answer (score 1):

Perfect participle. Having + past participle.

Comment: And the perfect active participle at that